# Windows authentication fails to connect after Java update

Tags: java, tomcat8, iis-8, isapi-redirect

We have an application which front end is on running on Tomcat 8.5, IIS 8.5 configured with isapi redirect. Everthing is working fine with java 8.92. But after upgrading Java to 8.211 windows authentication fails to connect with error

> SOAP Fault occurred: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set

Is there any configuration needs to be changed after Java update?

EDIT:

We have recreated Tomcat services after Java update. And if we enabe Anonymous Authentication in IIS everything works fine. But when only Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS we got that authentication failed error. There is only one error in logs

> SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-1443]]
>       org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:100)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:72)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1118)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:223)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:70)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
>           ... 13 more
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:301)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers(OpenSSLUtil.java:98)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:98)

Comment: Could you please tell me when you enabled the windows auth? In IIS or tomcat java application?

Comment: @BrandoZhang, in IIS